# How can I use wso2 to publish remote SOAP wsdl to REST APIs

Tags: rest, api, soap, wso2, publish

I hava a romote soap webservices wsdl and I need to consume it to publish as a rest api (json). I am using ubuntu 18. what do I have to downlaod and How can I use wso2 to publish remote SOAP wsdl to REST APIs?

Comment: That is a very broad question you are asking, and because of that there are multiple possible answers. Can you maybe elaborate a bit on where the remote WebService is, and if anything else needs to happen like a transformation, security etc?

Comment: I can only connect remote soap webservices via vpn using ipsec. It is  ot publicly available. I already establish  the secure way to comunicate to soap wsdl. Now I need to consume and publish as a rest api internalyy not publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably solve the problem with either API Manager or Enterprise Integrator. However if you are just exposing one API to your mobile app, both of these products would probably be serious overkill.

Comment: What do you mean "serious overkill"? Also does api manager work on u ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: it should run on ubuntu, however it has quite a footprint for the single task you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks,  I will try to use the Api Manager to see.

Comment: I want to download with update version and needs to be  WSO2 Subscription. How do I get  WSO2 Subscription do I can download api manager

Comment: If you want to get the latest updates on the product you need a Product Support subscription, this is a paid subscription.  For more info:  https://wso2.com/subscription
If not you can just download the latest release from their website. Or even build from scratch from their github.

Comment: I think I will need a product support build the idea that I have. At least I can cut the timing to buold it. Hovewer I am developer and dont belong to any company, and seems it doesnt accept my g m a i l. I send them a  mail, and hope to get some info to get the price list, so I can use choose the subscription.